BadRequestError when Summarizing with MapReduceDocumentsChain as a tool within AgentExecutor in langchain
I try to combine 3 models with one another within langchain and that an openai tools calling agent can call the correct model based on a question. I made StructuredTools from the chains and made sure that the tool returns the output of that chain when it is called. This works for my RAG tool and my statistics tool but not for the summarizer. For the summarizer I get this error:
BadRequestError: Error code: 400 - {'error': {'message': "This model's maximum context length is 8192 tokens. However, your messages resulted in 15188 tokens (14729 in the messages, 459 in the functions). Please reduce the length of the messages or functions.", 'type': 'invalid_request_error', 'param': 'messages', 'code': 'context_length_exceeded'}}
` So the number of tokens is too high.
This is that summarizer tool: 

def summary_maker():
    """This function will give back a summary of the emails. You should call this function when the user wants to get a summary of any kind. Also you can call this model if the user question is very broad
    such as:
    question: What did my competitors do in the last month?
    question: What did company X do this last month?
    """
    global docs

    document_variable_name = "context"
    llm_summary = load_llm(temp=temp, max_tokens_count=900)

    # # prompt for first summarizing each document
    prompt = PromptTemplate.from_template(imp_indiv_email_summarizer_prompt)

    # # map each document to an individual summary
    # map_chain = LLMChain(llm=llm_summary, prompt=prompt)
    
    # """The ReduceDocumentsChain handles taking the document mapping results "
    # and reducing them into a single output. It wraps a generic 
    # CombineDocumentsChain (like StuffDocumentsChain) but adds the ability 
    # to collapse documents before passing it to the CombineDocumentsChain if 
    # their cumulative size exceeds token_max.
    # So if the cumulative number of tokens in our mapped documents exceeds token_max
    # then we'll recursively pass in the documents in batches of < token_max tokens to our 
    # StuffDocumentsChain to create batched summaries.
    # see: https://python.langchain.com/v0.2/docs/tutorials/summarization/#map-reduce 
    # """

    # # We now define how to combine these summaries
    reduce_prompt = PromptTemplate.from_template(summary_reduce_prompt)

    # # and summarize the set of summaries
    reduce_llm_chain = LLMChain(llm=llm_summary, prompt=reduce_prompt)

    document_prompt = PromptTemplate(
        input_variables=["page_content"],
        template="{page_content}"
    )

    llm_chain = LLMChain(llm=llm_summary, prompt=prompt)
    
    combine_documents_chain = StuffDocumentsChain(
        llm_chain=reduce_llm_chain,
        document_prompt=document_prompt,
        document_variable_name=document_variable_name
    )

    # this should be called only if documents exeed context for 'StuffDocumentsChain'
    collapse_documents_chain = StuffDocumentsChain(
        llm_chain=llm_chain,
        document_prompt=document_prompt
        #document_variable_name=document_variable_name
    )
    # this is the final chain
    reduce_documents_chain = ReduceDocumentsChain(
        combine_documents_chain=combine_documents_chain,
        collapse_documents_chain=collapse_documents_chain,
        token_max=7000
    )
    chain = MapReduceDocumentsChain(
        llm_chain=llm_chain,
        reduce_documents_chain=reduce_documents_chain,
    )

    # out = chain.invoke({'input_documents' : docs})
    # return out

    # for the record, this is a very bad way of doing this (the fact that we take docs as global parameter and just add it as page_content). 
    # Preferably the page_content is dynamically taken as output of another agent (statistical model) so that you can dynamically get summaries of partial emails
    def get_summary(input: str) -> str:
        #print(input)
        #print("map_red input keys: ", map_reduce_documents_chain.input_keys)
        print(f"Number of documents: {len(docs)}")
        result = chain.invoke({"input_documents": docs})
        print(f"Summary length: {len(result)}")
        #print("result:", result)
        return result

    summary_tool = StructuredTool.from_function(func=get_summary,
                                description="""This function will give back a summary of the emails. You should call this function when the user wants to get a summary of any kind. Also you can call this model if the user question is very broad
                                such as:
                                question: What did my competitors do in the last month?
                                question: What did company X do this last month?
                                request: Give me a summary of X
                                """)
    return summary_tool

and here you can see how I initialize the tool-calling agent:
prompt3 = PromptTemplate.from_template(
""" Answer the following questions as best as you can. You have access to the following tools:\n 
Semantic email retrieval: Answers a question by converting it into a vector and finds the most similar email. Input should be the question and it will output the answer.
Use the following format:
Question: The input question you have to answer
Thought: you should always think about what to do
Action: the action to take should be one of [None, Semantic email retrieval]
Observation: the result of the action (this thought/action/observation can repeat N times)
Thought: I now know the final answer.
Final answer: the final answer to the original input question
Begin!
Question: {input}
Thought: {agent_scratchpad}
"""
)

# here we add the functions that in the end give us back the answer. 
tools = [semantic_email_retrieval(), statistical_and_regex_answering(), summary_maker()]
llm_integrate = load_llm(0, 1300)
# give the tools to a openai_tools_agent 
# for more info see (https://python.langchain.com/v0.1/docs/modules/agents/agent_types/tool_calling/)
agent = create_openai_tools_agent(llm_integrate, tools, prompt3)
# the agent executor will be the runtime so to say of this agent. It can for instance route the tasks to the right agent
agent_executor = AgentExecutor(agent=agent, tools=tools, return_intermediate_steps=True)
output = agent_executor.invoke({"input" : "Please summarize the emails"})
print(output)

I know that this problem only arises when using this with the tool-calling agent because when I just invoke the summarizer itself, I get no errors.
Also as you see right now the question input isn't used for the summarizer tool, rather it just passes all the documents now. This is not how I want it in the end but for now you can see that I am not passing all the documents through the tool-calling agent.

I tried making the llm_integrate have more tokens than the summarizer.
I tried the summarizer just as stand alone (without the tools calling agent) and that worked fine.


I found out the problem in my code. The get_summary function now returns also all documents. To have it only return the answer: changed the last line at get_summary into result['output_text']
